# SerialDevice write app closes with no warning after writting into a serial device a string. C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, arduino, read-write

I'm working on a project that has to send commands to an Arduino board using a Raspberry Pi. In the code, there is a void and a Task that is used to send those commands to the board. When you initialize the program the writing to the Arduino board works fine, therefore if you ask it to send a command it will and the Arduino will receive it. After running the program for some time, when you ask it to send a command it stops and the app crashes with no warning message except an error message that says 0x000000d.

The app works in the following way:

Arduino sends information to the program. When the program has received all the information it calculates certain variables based on the information and then sends a message to the Arduino. The Arduino sends information almost once every 1/10 of a second, therefore, the program sends a message to the Arduino at the same rate.

The code that sends and receives messages is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace KronosBrain
{
    class SeriDev
    {
        //SeriDev ---> Serial Device
        private static SerialDevice serialDevice = null;
        private static string message = "";
        private static bool isConnected = false;

        //Message sending related
        public static bool isCommandPoolRunning = false;
        public static bool isReadingCommand = false;
        //public static List<String> commandPool = new List<string>();
        private static string lastCommand = "";
        private static int lastCommandPetitions = 0;

        public static async void StartConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                UInt16 vid = 0x2A03;
                UInt16 pid = 0x0042;
                string deviceFilter = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(vid, pid);
                DeviceInformationCollection deviceInfo = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(deviceFilter);
                foreach (var device in deviceInfo)
                {
                    Info.WriteLine("<SeriDev> Looking for arduino devices... " + device.Id);
                }
                string device_id = deviceInfo.First().Id;
                serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(device_id);

                if (serialDevice == null)
                {
                    Info.WriteLine("<SeriDev> Device is null");
                    StartConnection();
                }

                // Configure serial settings
                serialDevice.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50); //Refresh write time
                serialDevice.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50); //Refresh read time
                serialDevice.BaudRate = 115200;
                serialDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;
                serialDevice.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
                serialDevice.DataBits = 8;
                serialDevice.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;
                //Settings done
                Info.WriteLine("<SeriDev> Connected to Arduino");
                isConnected = true;
                isCommandPoolRunning = false;
                isReadingCommand = false;

                ListenSerialDevice();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Server.LogMessage("Cannot connect with arduino... Waiting for connection");
                Info.WriteLine("<SeriDev> Connot connect with arduino, waiting for connection. Error message: " + ex.Message);
                //Add error messages
                StartConnection();
            }
        }

        private static async void ListenSerialDevice()
        {
            try
            {
                //Check for nullity
                if (serialDevice != null)
                {
                    DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(serialDevice.InputStream);


                    while (isConnected)
                    {
                        await Read(dataReader);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Server.LogMessage(String.Format("There was an error reading the input."));
                Info.WriteLine(String.Format("<SeriDev> There was an error reading the input. Error message {0}: ", ex.Message));
            }
        }

        private static async Task Read(DataReader dataReader)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!isCommandPoolRunning)
                {
                    isReadingCommand = true;
                    Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

                    var bufferLength = 32;
                    dataReader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                    loadAsyncTask = dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)bufferLength).AsTask();
                    dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

                    UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
                    isReadingCommand = false;
                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        string readInformation = "";
                        try
                        {
                            readInformation = dataReader.ReadString(bytesRead);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("<SeriDev> There was a problem converting the bytes to a string.");
                        }
                        //Debug.WriteLine(readInformation);

                        message += readInformation;
                        string[] messageSplited = message.Split('?');
                        for (int i = 0; i < messageSplited.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (i < (messageSplited.Length - 1))
                            {
                                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(messageSplited[i]))
                                {
                                    var task = Task.Run(() => HandleData(messageSplited[i]));
                                    task.Wait();
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                        message = messageSplited[(messageSplited.Length - 1)];
                    }
                    dataReader.DetachBuffer();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("<SeriDev> Something strange happened in Read. Error message {0}", ex.Message);
                isConnected = false;
                serialDevice = null;
                Debug.WriteLine("<SeriDev> Disconnected from arduino. Trying to reconnect");
                StartConnection();
            }
        }

        private static void HandleData(string data)
        {
            try
            {
                NumberFormatInfo provider = new NumberFormatInfo();
                provider.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
                //Debug.WriteLine("<SeriDev> Message cleaned: " + data);
                //Split data to find coordinates and other information
                string[] keyWords = data.Split('!');
                //Debug.WriteLine("KeyWord[0]: " + keyWords[0] + " KeyWord[1]: " + keyWords[1]);
                if (keyWords.Length > 1)
                {
                    switch (keyWords[0])
                    {
                        case "gps_x":
                            SelfDriving.robot.x = Convert.ToDouble(keyWords[1], provider);
                            //Server.SendMessage("gps_x$" + SelfDriving.robot.x);
                            break;
                        case "gps_y":
                            SelfDriving.robot.y = Convert.ToDouble(keyWords[1], provider);
                            //Server.SendMessage("gps_y$" + SelfDriving.robot.x);
                            break;
                        case "frontU":
                            SelfDriving.robot.frontU = Convert.ToDouble(keyWords[1], provider);
                            //Server.SendMessage("front_u$" + SelfDriving.robot.frontU);
                            break;
                        case "leftU":
                            SelfDriving.robot.leftU = Convert.ToDouble(keyWords[1], provider);
                            //Server.SendMessage("left_u$" + SelfDriving.robot.leftU);
                            break;
                        case "rightU":
                            SelfDriving.robot.rightU = Convert.ToDouble(keyWords[1], provider);
                            //Server.SendMessage("right_u$" + SelfDriving.robot.rightU);
                            break;
                        case "heading":
                            SelfDriving.robot.heading = Convert.ToDouble(keyWords[1], provider);
                            //Server.SendMessage("heading$" + SelfDriving.robot.heading);
                            break;
                        case "gps_fix":
                            Server.SendMessage("gps_fix$" + keyWords[1]);
                            break;
                        case "robotInformationComplete":
                            if (!SelfDriving.isAnalyzing)
                            {
                                //Info.WriteLine("<SeriDev> Calling PreAnalyzerEngine");
                                SelfDriving.hasFix = true;
                                SelfDriving.PreAnalyzerEngine();
                            }
                            break;
                        case "noFix":
                            SelfDriving.hasFix = false;
                            Server.LogMessage("Waiting for fix");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Debug.WriteLine("<SeriDev> Default case {0}", message);
                            Server.LogMessage(message);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("<SeriDev> Handling data failed. Error message: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public static async void SendMessage(string command)
        {
            isCommandPoolRunning = true;
            if (!isReadingCommand)
            {
                var task = Task.Run(() => CommandPoolEmptier(command));
                task.Wait();
            }            
            isCommandPoolRunning = false;
        }

        public static async Task CommandPoolEmptier(string command)
        {
            try
            {
                Task<UInt32> storeAsyncTask;
                DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(serialDevice.OutputStream);

                char[] buffer = new char[command.Length];
                command.CopyTo(0, buffer, 0, command.Length);
                String InputString = new string(buffer);
                dataWriter.WriteString(InputString);

                storeAsyncTask = dataWriter.StoreAsync().AsTask();

                UInt32 bytesWritten = await storeAsyncTask;
                if (bytesWritten >= buffer.Length)
                {
                    dataWriter.DetachBuffer();
                    Debug.WriteLine("<SeriDev> Sent.");
                }
                //await dataWriter.FlushAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("There was an error writing the output. Error message {0}: ", ex.Message);
                Server.LogMessage(String.Format("There was an error writing the output. Error message {0}: ", ex.Message));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Arduino code that sends and receives messages is the following:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_HMC5883_U.h>

//Declare compass
Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified compass = Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified(12345);

//Declare ultrasonic sensors
int frontEcho = 30;
int frontTrigger = 31;
float frontDistance, frontDuration;
int leftEcho = 32;
int leftTrigger = 33;
float leftDistance, leftDuration;
int rightEcho = 34;
int rightTrigger = 35;
float rightDistance, rightDuration;

//GPS
HardwareSerial mySerial = Serial1;  //hablar al GPS
Adafruit_GPS GPS(&Serial1);  //GPS object
#define GPSECHO  true
char c;   //leer datos del GPS
String NMEA1;
String NMEA2;

//Motors
//MOTORSHIELD
Adafruit_MotorShield afms = Adafruit_MotorShield();
//MOTORS
Adafruit_DCMotor *m1 = afms.getMotor(4);
Adafruit_DCMotor *m2 = afms.getMotor(3);
Adafruit_DCMotor *m3 = afms.getMotor(1);
Adafruit_DCMotor *m4 = afms.getMotor(2);

//Voids
float angle()
{
  //Get compass event
  sensors_event_t event; 
    compass.getEvent(&event);

    //Calculate angle when z is pointing upwards
    float heading = atan2(event.magnetic.y, event.magnetic.x);

    float declinationAngle = 0.0139626;
    heading += declinationAngle;

    //Correct signs
    // Correct for when signs are reversed.
    if(heading < 0)
      heading += 2*PI;

    // Check for wrap due to addition of declination.
    if(heading > 2*PI)
      heading -= 2*PI;

  //Convert from radians to degrees
  float headingDegrees = heading * 180/M_PI; 

  return headingDegrees;
}

void Stop()
{
  m1->run(RELEASE); 
  m2->run(RELEASE); 
  m3->run(RELEASE); 
  m4->run(RELEASE); 
}

void Forwards(int speed)
{
  speed = map(speed, 0, 100, 0, 255);
  m1->run(FORWARD);
  m2->run(FORWARD);
  m3->run(FORWARD);
  m4->run(FORWARD);
  m1->setSpeed(speed);
  m2->setSpeed(speed);
  m3->setSpeed(speed);
  m4->setSpeed(speed);
}

void Left(int speed)
{
  speed = map(speed, 0, 100, 0, 255);
  m1->run(BACKWARD);
  m2->run(FORWARD);
  m3->run(BACKWARD);
  m4->run(FORWARD);
  m1->setSpeed(speed);
  m2->setSpeed(speed);
  m3->setSpeed(speed);
  m4->setSpeed(speed);
}

void Right(int speed)
{
  speed = map(speed, 0, 100, 0, 255);
  m1->run(FORWARD);
  m2->run(BACKWARD);
  m3->run(FORWARD);
  m4->run(BACKWARD);
  m1->setSpeed(speed);
  m2->setSpeed(speed);
  m3->setSpeed(speed);
  m4->setSpeed(speed);
}

//ULTRASONIC SENSORS
float FrontUCalc(){
  digitalWrite(frontTrigger, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(1);
  digitalWrite(frontTrigger, LOW);
  frontDuration = pulseIn(frontEcho, HIGH);
  frontDistance = (frontDuration / 58.2);

  return frontDistance;
}

float LeftUCalc(){
  digitalWrite(leftTrigger, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(1);
  digitalWrite(leftTrigger, LOW);
  leftDuration = pulseIn(leftEcho, HIGH);
  leftDistance = (leftDuration / 58.2);

  return leftDistance;
}

float RightUCalc(){
  digitalWrite(rightTrigger, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(1);
  digitalWrite(rightTrigger, LOW);
  rightDuration = pulseIn(rightEcho, HIGH);
  rightDistance = (rightDuration / 58.2);

  return rightDistance;
}

void ReadSerial()
{
  String readData = "";
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    delay(1);
    while(Serial.available() > 0){
        // statement
      readData = Serial.readString();
    }
  }

  if(readData != ""){
      HandleData(readData);
  }
}

void HandleData(String data)
{
  if(data == "s")
  {
    //Serial.print(data + "!0?");
    Stop();
  }
  if(data == "g")
  {
    //Serial.print(data + "!0?");
    Forwards(90);
  }
  if(data == "r")
  {
    //Serial.print(data + "!0?");
    Right(60);
  }
  if(data == "l")
  {
    //Serial.print(data + "!0?");
    Left(60);
  }
}

float GetLatitude()
{
  //ReadGPS();
  float latitude;

  if(GPS.fix == 1){
      latitude = GPS.latitudeDegrees;
  }

  return latitude;
}

float GetLongitude()
{
  //ReadGPS();
  float longitude;

  if(GPS.fix == 1){
      longitude = GPS.longitudeDegrees; 
  }

  return longitude;
}

void ReadGPS()
{
  while(!GPS.newNMEAreceived())
  {
    c = GPS.read();
  }
  GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA());
  NMEA1 = GPS.lastNMEA();
  while(!GPS.newNMEAreceived())
  {
    c = GPS.read();
  }
  GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA());
  NMEA2 = GPS.lastNMEA();
}

void ClearGPS()
{
  while(!GPS.newNMEAreceived())
  {
    c = GPS.read();
  }
  GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA());
  while(!GPS.newNMEAreceived())
  {
    c = GPS.read();
  }
  GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA());
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.print("\n////////////////////////////////////////");
  Serial.print("\nDRAPSOR 2017 - KRONOS II - Active"); 
  Serial.print("\n////////////////////////////////////////");
  Serial.print("\n");


  if(!compass.begin())
  {
    /* There was a problem detecting the HMC5883 ... check your connections */
    Serial.println("Compass could not initialize, chek wiring.");
    while(1);
  }

  //GPS
  //GPS.sendCommand("$PMTK251,38400*27<CR><LF>"); // Change GPS baud to 38400 
  GPS.begin(9600);

  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_10HZ); 
  //GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCGGA);

  //GPS.begin(9600);
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCONLY);
  GPS.sendCommand("$PGCMD,33,0*66");
  //GPS.begin(38400);
  //delay(250); //Pause
  //GPS.sendCommand("$PMTK220,100*2F<CR><LF>"); // 10 Hz update rate
  Serial.println("Finished GPS Setup");
  //delay(500); //Pause

  delay(1000);

  //MOTORS
  afms.begin();
  m1->setSpeed(0);  //v inicio motor
  m1->run(FORWARD);
  m1->run(FORWARD);
  m1->run(RELEASE);  //v = 0 --> como apagar

  m2->setSpeed(0);  
  m2->run(FORWARD);
  m2->run(FORWARD);
  m2->run(RELEASE);  

  m3->setSpeed(0);  
  m3->run(FORWARD);
  m3->run(FORWARD);
  m3->run(RELEASE);  

  m4->setSpeed(0);  
  m4->run(FORWARD);
  m4->run(FORWARD);
  m4->run(RELEASE);  

  //ULTRASONIC SENSORS
  pinMode(frontEcho, INPUT);
  pinMode(frontTrigger, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(leftEcho, INPUT);
  pinMode(leftTrigger, OUTPUT);  

  pinMode(rightEcho, INPUT);
  pinMode(rightTrigger, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  ReadSerial();
  ReadGPS();
  ReadSerial();
  if(GPS.fix)
  {
    Serial.print("heading!" + (String)angle());
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("?");
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("frontU!" + (String)FrontUCalc());
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("?");
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("leftU!" + (String)LeftUCalc());
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("?");
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("rightU!" + (String)RightUCalc());
    Serial.print("?");
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("gps_fix!" + (String)GPS.fix);
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("?");
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("gps_x!");
    Serial.print(GetLatitude(), 13);
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("?");
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("gps_y!");
    Serial.print(GetLongitude(), 13);
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("?");
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("robotInformationComplete!");
    ReadSerial();
    Serial.print("?");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print("gps_fix!0");
    Serial.print("?");
    Serial.print("noFix!");
    Serial.print("?");
  }
}
```

So when Arduino sends 'robotInformationComplete!' HandleData is fired, then, the program calls another class which based on the received information it either sends trough CommandPoolEmptier 'g', 's', 'l' o 'r'. Since the Arduino sends the 'robotInformationCompelte!' every tenth of a second the program sends a command every same time.

To simulate the program, go to the HandleData void and in the 'case "robotInformationComplete":' change:

```
//Info.WriteLine("<SeriDev> Calling PreAnalyzerEngine");
SelfDriving.hasFix = true;
SelfDriving.PreAnalyzerEngine();
```

For:

```
SelfDriving.hasFix = true;
Task.Delay(5);
SendMessage("g");
```

Task delay will simulate the time that takes for the program to calculate those variables and then it will send a message.

In the program, when you call SendCommand various times it collapses making the app crash. I've tried many different possible solutions but none of them have worked.

Comment: If it helps, also every so often it displays the following message:Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

Answer (score 0):

Derive from [official code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess), it make `WriteCancelLock` to avoid device `OutputStream` non-blocking.

```
private async Task WriteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    Task<UInt32> storeAsyncTask;

    if ((WriteBytesAvailable) && (WriteBytesInputValue.Text.Length != 0))
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[WriteBytesInputValue.Text.Length];
        WriteBytesInputValue.Text.CopyTo(0, buffer, 0, WriteBytesInputValue.Text.Length);
        String InputString = new string(buffer);
        DataWriteObject.WriteString(InputString);
        WriteBytesInputValue.Text = "";

        // Don't start any IO if we canceled the task
        lock (WriteCancelLock)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // Cancellation Token will be used so we can stop the task operation explicitly
            // The completion function should still be called so that we can properly handle a canceled task
            storeAsyncTask = DataWriteObject.StoreAsync().AsTask(cancellationToken);
        }

        UInt32 bytesWritten = await storeAsyncTask;
        if (bytesWritten > 0)
        {
            WriteBytesTextBlock.Text += InputString.Substring(0, (int)bytesWritten) + '\n';
            WriteBytesCounter += bytesWritten;
            UpdateWriteBytesCounterView();
        }
        rootPage.NotifyUser("Write completed - " + bytesWritten.ToString() + " bytes written", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        rootPage.NotifyUser("No input received to write", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
    }

}
```

I have tried send message with your code. Unfortunately, I could not reproduce your issue, I guess the message too short to non-blocking I/O. You could create a `WriteAsync` method like the code sample to exclude the above suppose.

Comment: The solution didn't work because the WriteCancelLock works to manually stop the sending of a message. My problem appeared when a lot of commands where sent one after the other. In my case, a command is sent approximately once every tenth of a second. If it would help I could upload the code that starts sending commands and the Arduino code that receives them. Thank you for the solution anyway!!

Comment: I have updated the post with a more detailed explanation and more code so it's possible to replicate the problem. I hope this is enough to find a solution, if you need more information or code, please ask.